# How to join two worksheets based on the data they contain

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I would like some help on how to join two different worksheets that I receive every week.

Sheet 1 contains information on the defects that were observed during a week (#defect, type of defect, #quality control) and Sheet 2 contains info on the corrective actions that need to be taken for these defects (#defect, corrective action, responsible person, date of completion).

I want to unite these data and create a new worksheet with the following columns: #defect, type of defect, #quality control, corrective action, respons. pers, date of completion.

I tried with the VLOOKUP function but I face two problems:

1.) When I tried to VLOOKUP the lookup value #defect(Defects worksheet) in the Corrective Action table array I miss some results because one defect can have more than one corrective actions

2.) When I tried to VLOOKUP the lookupvalue #defect(Corrective actions worksheet) in the Defects table array I also miss some results because not every defect has a corrective action.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: First I thought this might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4160243/2745865 (what is really being asked here is how to make equivalent of an SQL outer join in Excel, unless I understood it wrong) but the issue of multiple matching rows adds to that, though...

Comment: Are you searching how to automate the task or is it ok if the solution works partly by manual (pre)processing of the data?

Comment: I prefer to have it automated, as I have a lot more columns than those described, but if my only choice is to have a part to be done manually I could do it as well!

Comment: Could it be possible for you to import the data into a SQL database? There this would be quite easy (a full outer join between the two data sets), but doing it in Excel might be a bit hard (at least with simple cell formulas, with VBA it probably is feasible).

Comment: No it wouldn't be possible because I am not familiar with it

Comment: I can think of a possible solution (with some automation, some manual work), but I have a question. Are the defects in the Defect worksheet unique (i.e. there are no duplicate defect IDs in the Defect worksheet)?

Comment: In the defect worksheet they are unique. Only in the corrective action worksheets there might be duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to perform this is to create a macro that does all the required things automatically. The downside is that it will likely be suboptimal performance-wise, since the operations required fit poorly to the available functionality in Excel.

Given worksheets Sheet1, Sheet2 and Result, and the sheets

```
#defect type    #quality
4       B       574
1       A       34
2       C       7564
3       A       23
5       A       783
6       B       23
```

and

```
#defect action  person  completion
1       foo     John    2.10.2011
3       bar     Eric    14.8.2012
4       zzzz    John    16.2.2013
3       asdf    Jeff    2.8.2012
```

and result sheet column layout as

```
#defect type    #quality    action  person  completion
```

the following macro should do what is being asked (*fixed the bugs and some of the performance issues found in the original version*):

```
Sub doFullOuterJoin()
'
' Perform what SQL terminology calls full outer join on two sheets
'
'
    Dim defectRange As Range
    Dim actionRange As Range
    Dim resultSheet As Worksheet

    Set defectRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:C999") ' the data range 1
    Set actionRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:D999") ' the data range 2
    Set resultSheet = Worksheets("Result")

    defRangeCols = defectRange.Columns.Count
    actRangeCols = actionRange.Columns.Count

    resRow = 2 ' result sheet row number to start filling data at
    lastMatch = 0 ' used to keep track of last matching index to improve performance
    For Each rw In defectRange.Rows
        ' process defects one at a time
        defectId = rw.Cells(1, 1)
        If (defectId = "") Then Exit For
        actIndex = 1
        Do
            ' find all the actions for the current defect
            matchedAction = VLookupRow(defectId, actionRange, lastMatch + 1)
            If (matchedAction = 0) Then
                ' no matching action was found
                If (actIndex = 1) Then
                    ' no actions at all, but copy defect record anyway
                    rw.Copy (resultSheet.Cells(resRow, 1))
                    resRow = resRow + 1
                End If
                lastMatch = 0
                Exit Do ' move on to next defect
            Else
                ' a matching action was found
                rw.Copy (resultSheet.Cells(resRow, 1)) ' copy defect record
                ' copy action data
                actionRange.Cells(matchedAction, 2).Resize(1, actRangeCols - 1).Copy
                resultSheet.Cells(resRow, defRangeCols + 1).Select
                resultSheet.Paste
                actIndex = actIndex + 1
                lastMatch = matchedAction
            End If
            resRow = resRow + 1
        Loop Until actIndex = 999
    Next rw
End Sub


Function VLookupRow(lookup_value, table_array As Range, Optional start_row As Long) As Integer
' Do VLOOKUP-like operation with optionally given start position
' This allows searching sequentially for the rest of matching rows with rather good performance
    Dim nRow As Long

    If (start_row = 0) Then start_row = 1 ' no start row provided, start at first row

    With table_array
        For nRow = start_row To .Rows.Count
            If .Cells(nRow, 1).Value = lookup_value Then
                VLookupRow = nRow
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next nRow
    End With
End Function
```

Basically this will run through the defect rows (Sheet1) one by one, copy the data to result sheet (Result) and find all matching action rows(Sheet2) and copy those, too, to the result sheet. It will stop when encountering the first row with empty #defect in Sheet1.
However, the code is a bit slow, does copying of the data a bit awkwardly. It should, however, allow quite easy modification for different sizes of data ranges, and with some tuning it might prove effective enough for the task.

Comment: I will check it and I will let you know :)

Comment: @liaites Sorry there is a infinite loop in the code, it was not intended. Also it failes to fetch the date for corrective action. I'll update the answer soon with corrections.

Comment: @liaites Now the fixed version is available, and the performance is also improved (the original was pretty bad actually).